# angular.copy() vs $.extend(true, {}, obj)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Just wanted to know if there is any difference between `angular.copy()` vs `$jquery.extend(true, {}, obj)` ?

As per [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) and [api.jquery.com/jquery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend), Both seem to be doing a deep clone, but jquery's method seems to be much faster.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you read the code?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy and https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ seems to point that both are doing a deep copy

Comment: Daniel can you be a bit more specific ?

Comment: You shouldn't think about comparing the two. What is angular and what is jquery -a framework and a library. That is why in an angularjs controller or a service you don't mess with jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `$.extend()` allows you to conditionally add key-value pairs to the extended object.

```
var sourceObj = { foo: 'bar' };
var destObj = $.extend(sourceObj, { added: 'addedProp'});
```

destObj is equal to:

```
{foo: "bar", added: "addedProp"}
```

Another difference I recently discovered, is that `angular.copy` will ignore a property called `$$hashKey` which Angular internally adds to objects inside `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I did a quick performance test and $.extend of Jquery seems be much faster than angular.copy which leads me to think ideally we should always use $.extend. Why would anyone use angular.copy at all ?

Comment: If you're already using jQuery and you're not adding jQuery just because `$.extend` is faster, then I don't see why not choose `$.extend` over `angular.copy`.

Comment: I recently came over this problem and saw that angular.copy will freeze the whole application (Windows Phone) if the object is to big (7.5 MB e.g.) $.extend is working like a charm in this situation.